# Using rotate to balance a red-black tree?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, search-trees, balanced-search-trees

> You have a Black-Red Tree of height `h` that has two childs:
>
> - Left child is a full binary tree of height `h-1`
> - Right child is a full binary tree of height `h-3`
>
> Balance the tree so both childs of root are of the same height (you don't have to keep the other nodes balanced, just the root).

---

From Wikipedia I understood that:

> When a subtree is rotated, the subtree side upon which it is rotated
>   increases its height by one node while the other subtree decreases its
>   height. This makes tree rotations useful for rebalancing a tree.

So the solution would be to right-rotate the root, and then the left and right childs' heights will become `h-2`.

However it doesn't work well:
[image: right-rotate]

The left child node height did decrease by one, but the right child node increased by two!

1. Why is it happening? Is wikipedia wrong?
2. How can I do it otherwise?

Comment: Do you understand how B-trees work?

Comment: @Raphael Not really, I'm talking about red-black trees here.

Comment: @iTayb: What you're missing is that each of the white nodes in your diagram is actually the root of some subtree. Rotations rebalance the *global* height. If you're talking about RB-trees, then you don't have to worry about heights at all: as long as the colors are properly assigned, the tree is balanced. Rotations in RB-trees are only supposed to preserve the invariant.

Comment: @quicksort Sorry, i don't get what you mean. I'm also talking about the global height. I know that I don't need to care about rotations, but this specific question is about how to make the left and right childrens of the root to have the same height. I thought that rotations might come handy here, because I can't think of another way to do it. I might be wrong.

Comment: @iTayb Too bad, because RB-trees are basically a special case of B-trees, written in a convoluted way. See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Analogy_to_B-trees_of_order_4). Personally, I find B-trees easier to understand, and then RB-trees follow.